# IOS sdk 4.3 and camera effects like mirror, blur, thermal... etc?

Tags: ios

There were many voices about camera effects on IOS SDK 4.3 (as you can read [here](http://www.theiphoneguru.net/2011/01/12/new-iphone-camera-effects-found-in-ios-4-3-files/)), after the final release i can't find anything about that on [Apple API change log](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS43APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010594).
Was it my fault and i made inaccurate research with google and Documentation ? Anyone knows anything more about this subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These effects are available via PhotoBooth on the iPad2 but not in the SDK as for as I am aware. Looking at the names PBThermalFilter for example it'd seem that may be the case.